# configure juju with openstack using keystone

Tags: juju, openstack

I am trying to integrate juju with openstack. I have a virtual machine and on that I have installed openstack grizzly using devstack script. Now I want to configure juju with openstack (want to configure using keystone, not swift), so that I can create openstack instances using juju.

Here is my environment.yaml,

root@ubuntutcs:~/.juju# cat environments.yaml

environments:

     openstack:

     type: openstack

     control-bucket: juju-openstack-myproject-95ec-8c2083e67721

     admin-secret: foooooooo

     auth-mode: userpass

     auth-url: http://myhost:5000/v2.0/

     username: demo

     password: openstack

     project-name: demo

     default-series: precise

     default-instance-type: m1.small

     default-image-id: 60eb0af4-03f9-4d35-a858-3da302380937

     s3-uri: http://myhost:3333

     combined-key: 095b11767c084842b34e14ce2646b67e

     secret-key: fce90f6069fd4ab4bce4f4b28be49e26

root@ubuntutcs:~/.juju#

And I am getting following error,

root@ubuntutcs:~/.juju#

root@ubuntutcs:~/.juju# juju bootstrap -v --debug 

2013-08-18 07:04:01 INFO juju provider.go:115 environs/openstack: opening environment "openstack"

2013-08-18 07:04:01 WARNING juju config.go:133 config attribute "default-image-id" (60eb0af4-03f9-4d35-a858-3da302380937) is deprecated and ignored, use simplestreams metadata instead

2013-08-18 07:04:01 WARNING juju config.go:138 config attribute "default-instance-type" (m1.small) is deprecated and ignored

2013-08-18 07:04:01 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:429 unknown config field "project-name"

2013-08-18 07:04:01 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:429 unknown config field "s3-uri"

2013-08-18 07:04:01 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:429 unknown config field "combined-key"

2013-08-18 07:04:01 ERROR juju supercommand.go:235 command failed: required environment variable not set for credentials attribute: TenantName

error: required environment variable not set for credentials attribute: TenantName

root@ubuntutcs:~/.juju#

Please help me to understand the error.

Answer (score 3):

Juju configuration uses the attribute "tenant-name" to refer to the name of the project/tenant on Openstack. So where you have "project-name: demo" in your configuration, you need to replace "project-name" with "tenant-name"